# Logstash split JSON array

Tags: json, split, logstash

I'm using the following filter to split a JSON array so that I have one message per data in array:

```
input {
  stdin {}
}
filter {
  split {
    field => "results"
  }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The input I send is:

```
{"results" : [{"id": "a1", "name": "hello"}, {"id": "a2", "name": "logstash"}]}
```

Yet, the output is a single message with the following error:

```
[main] Only String and Array types are splittable. field:results is of type = NilClass

/logstash-7.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib/awesome_print/formatters/base_formatter.rb:31: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
{
       "message" => "{\"results\" : [{\"id\": \"a1\", \"name\": \"hello\"}, {\"id\": \"a2\", \"name\": \"logstash\"}]}",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2019-10-18T14:07:57.285Z,
          "host" => "C02Z40E8LVDR",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_split_type_failure"
    ]
}
```

Any hint?
Many thanks. Christian

Answer (score 2):

As documented in Logstash website: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

You should use the JSON filter plugin, by applying

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

Instead of the `split` filter.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works. One thing that I don't quite understand is why the source in the filter is "message" whilst the json I'm interested in is in "result"?

Comment: @Christian68 it's how Logstash indentifies the body of the input. I'm glad it worked, don't forget  to mark it as `answer` to help others find it.